# improving performance in very big wpf grid

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, grid, rendering

Let' s say I have a grid which size is: [650, 540]
in each cell there is a UIElement like a rectangle or an ellipse

The grid is filled at the beggining and never modified in the entire life of the program

[as you can see it's placed inside a scrollviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL8rS.png)

the problem is that as it is the program is absolutely not usable because of its slowness

should i consider changing from WPF to another library or there is a way to make it faster? can you suggest something?

thank you in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of such a Grid? Why not use a bitmap instead?

Comment: @Clemens by pressing controls user can move forward o backward highlighting nearby cells with the same "shape".

Are you suggesting using a Canvas instead of Grid? I thought Grid was more the "right" thing to use in wpf, since the affinity with the structure I' m going to reppresent
Also I thought in a way of "scalability" (the grid is not always [650, 540], it's just the max size) due to the vector graphics property of wpf grid

Comment: @Clemens, oh.. or maybe you mean use bitmap instead of UIelements?

Comment: No, I meant to use a single bitmap instead of the whole Grid. You said that it is "never modified". Apparently that isn't true when you want to highlight cells.

Comment: @Clemens yes I' m sorry, what I'm doing is just put a yellow rectangle on top of the shapes.
Shapes by the way stay the same
http://i.imgur.com/Iwb7RsM.png

Comment: Then you should create a bitmap with all the shapes and use it as the Background of an empty Grid (in an ImageBrush). Then add yellow rectangles to whatever Grid cells they need to be in.

Comment: make a fake scrollbar (scrollviewer) and use a small grid (eg 20 x20) , then  load  relevant elements to the grid dynamically while scrolling to left/right .(sorry for my English)

Comment: @MitraM it's not possible since the user can zoom in and out

Comment: @Clemens yes, if there is not other way out, i' m going to do that way

Comment: "the user can zoom in and out" is also something that you haven't told us anything about in your question.

Comment: @Clemens did it just made you come up with a great idea?

Comment: @Clemens I guess not...

Answer (score 1):

Use bitmaps instead of shapes.  WPF is drawing all the shape whenever you scroll.

Comment: thank you, but it' s the only way? must be a way to make wpf render only the visible shapes

Comment: Quite certainly a single Shape is less costly than a bitmap. You would have to render 650x540 bitmaps here. I guess that won't work at all.

Comment: @Clemens you pre-render the bitmaps